# Is this a normal operating temperature range for a New Third-Generation MacBook Air (2.13 MHz, 120 GB SSD)?

Tags: temperature, macbook

Even with just my text editor open (no web browser) and maybe the terminal, the baseline temperature is usually **above 40 C**. When i open 4-5 browser tabs in Safari (even if none of Sites have Flash) the temp can quickly go **over 50 C**.  (In addition, i am observing these temps even though i have turned the fan up to 3000 rpms).

(i have install smcFanControl on my MBA so i can see the temp in the menu bar.)

So this means my MBA is running much warmer than my MBP; and in practice, it means that i have to be very careful how i use my MBA.

Of course if i load a Site with Flash, it just freaks out, and often quickly goes above 65 C (I've installed a flash blocker to avoid this).

Is anyone else observing this behavior?  I have checked the Apple boards and sure enough, there are a lot of complaints, but nothing from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak on the normal operating range of the Air, but my MacBook sits normally at 60 C. (135 F).

If I start doing some major work (MAMP Pro, TextMate, Photoshop, Transmit, 10+ FF tabs) it gets up to about 165 F. Hulu will run it hot, 180 F easily.

I haven't noticed any issues and am pretty sure it's not going to kill it to run hot.

Answer (score 2):

Im not an expert, but I dont think 65 C is considered a dangerous temp. I would say about 80 is getting borderline risky but anything below that should be fine.

Also, im sure if the laptop thought it was getting too hot it would shut down before any damage was done so if that not happening then its probably fine.

Comment: @COnnor - Not so sure about automatic shut down. For the record, I've had an HP lappie's gfx card on the high 80's or low 90's. My new iMac (first Apple computer) runs warm and i called them about it. They said it was normal.